# How to find the eigen values

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

How to find the eigen values of the graph having vertex set as $\{1,2,.......n\}$ and edge set as $\{(l,l+1)\}$ $ \cup (1,n)$ ? 
 where $1\le l \le n$.

Here I am considering the Laplacian matrix of the graph.

Please give some hints . I am totally clueless.

Comment: I think here is a typo error. Is $I$ has to be replaced by $l$?

Comment: I have edited it @G _0 pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cycle graph. I expect here the edges are undirected type. Hence your Laplacian matrix is $$L=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1\\ -1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2 & -1\\ -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$ This is a circulant matrix and for a circulant matrix the eigenvalues are already obtained. Using that you can get its eigenvalues.  Otherwise, observe that $L=2I_n-\mathcal{P}_n-\mathcal{P}_n^T,$ where $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the full-cycle permutation matrix. As ${\rm det}(\mathcal{P}_n-\lambda I_n)=(-1)^n(\lambda^n-1)$, the eigenvalues of $\mathcal{P}_n$ are the primitive $n$th roots of unity ($1, \omega, \ldots, \omega^{n-1}$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi\mathtt{i}}{n}}$). Further $\mathcal{P}_n^T=\mathcal{P}_n^{n-1}$. So the eigenvalues of $L$ are given by \begin{align*}2-\omega^k+\omega^{n-k}&=2-\omega^k-\omega^{-k}\\&=2-2\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}\\&=4\sin^2\frac{\pi k}{n}, ~~~~\text{ for }k=1, \ldots, n.\end{align*}

Comment: I am having many problems ;so I am listing them in order as:

Comment: 1.I think $P_n $ should be of the form $1\mapsto 2 ,2\mapsto 3,\ldots n\mapsto 1$ ,Is it ?I have seen that $L=2I_n-P_n-P_n^T$ for $n=3$ ;How to prove it in general ?Is it by induction?      2.In order to compute the eigen values we need to solve $\det(L-\lambda I)=\det (2I-P-P^T-\lambda I)$ what next ,please give the steps in order so that I can understand

Comment: How to get $P_n^T=P_n^{n-1}$

Comment: You can easily prove using induction technique 
-   $$\mathcal{P}_n^T=\mathcal{P}_n^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Here $\mathcal{P}_n$ is a full cycle permutation matrix. So if $\mathcal{P}_n=(p_{ij})$, then $$p_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } j=i+1 (\text{mod } n)\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: As the set of eigenvectors of $I_n, \mathcal{P}_n$ and $\mathcal{P}_n^T=\mathcal{P}_n^{n-1}$ are the same, the eigenvalues of  
$L$ can be obtained as described earlier.